# Low pass filter-Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, filtering, signal-processing

I am trying to use low pass filter on my data. My sample data is for every minute and I want to filter it with the time constant of 1440(daily). 
It is just writing a for loop that computes the filtering and appending the data into the y(filtered data) list.

Following is the code that I have written:

```
OD_deltaT=df["OD_deltaT"].values.tolist()
#a=1/(timeconstant)+1
a=1/1441
u, y=[0], []
for i, x in enumerate(OD_deltaT,1):
    u.append(x)
    y[1]=u[1]
    y[i]=(1-a)*y[i-1]+(a)*u[i]
```

But I get this error:

```
list index out of range.
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: what do you think `u, y=[0], []` accomplishes? with respect to `u`? I am not sure it does...

Comment: An empty list for y and an initial value of zero for u.

Comment: You could just use the filter from scipy: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.lfilter.html#scipy.signal.lfilter

Comment: Ok, so  .. `y` is `[]` ... what do you think `y[1]=u[1]` will do then ... what was your error? something about indexes out of range?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to append your data, like your did for `u`. You can also write the code in a little bit more concise way:

```
u = [0]
y = [0]
for x in OD_deltaT:
    u.append(x)
    y.append((1-a)*y[-1])+a*x)
```

Of course, `scipy` filters would do this faster ;)

Comment: Thanks a lot!you are right, scipy does that faster.

Comment: But it's a good exercise to understand what they are doing, especially when you enter the world of non LTI and where scipy cannot help anymore.

Comment: why is y[-1]? In my formula I meant taking one y before the current one.

Comment: The last one in the list is the one before the current one, because we are just about to add a new entry.